# Create query in Criteria API

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate Criteria API. Can you help me get a list of id's like this SQL query.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT id FROM upload_rdp idx WHERE idx.is_update_stat = 0 AND 
(SELECT COUNT(r_a.id) FROM rdp r_a WHERE r_a.upload_rdp_id = idx.id) = 
(SELECT COUNT(r_cv.id) FROM rdp r_cv WHERE r_cv.upload_rdp_id = idx.id AND
r_cv.is_checked_valid = 1) ORDER BY idx.id;
```

Here is a code, where I get a list of the first query. The SQL query is:

```
SELECT id FROM upload_rdp idx WHERE idx.is_update_stat = 0;
```

Using the Criteria API:

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria().addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("isUpdateStat", 0));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
criteria.list();
```

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: What did you get? What do you expect? What is your real problem?

Comment: HI. Thanks for comment.
I want to create this query in criteria API.
My problem is in creation this subqueries in criteria API.

Comment: Hello @Heri can you show your entities mappings? Please.

Comment: Your English is not so bad, but reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) could significantly improve it with only a little effort.